# Loading Gif Jquery $.Post(function)

Tags: jquery, post, animated-gif

I was wondering if there was a quick and easy way to put a loading gif int a jquery $.Post function?
I am thinking I would most likely have to put it into the body of the function somehow.  I want to kind of overlay the page in a kind of haze, with that spinny Loading gif, or maybe the horizontal barbershop bar thingy.  I have the images in my mvc images folder already,  Just need to figure out my options for implementing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assmume there is an event which occurs to start the ajax post off? In which case, you would need to display your loading image before calling the ajax. Then when the call returns, you would need to hide the loading image.

For example:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    // show loading image
    $("#loadingImage").show();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            // Your logic here...

            // hide loading image
            $("#loadingImage").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Load data" />
<img src="loading.gif" id="loadingImage" style="display: none;" />
```

Comment: That call to $("loadingImage").show(); what is that precisely?  Also, this is the $.post not $.ajax call.  They are similary infact, I believe post is a rapper for ajax.  So I would probably be doing this in the function section of the post function.

Comment: The `.show()` is what makes the image appear. It is equivalent to `.css("display", "block")`. You are correct that `$.post` relies on `$.ajax` so the two share methods.

Comment: I  meant, what is the part between the quotes?  Is that a link to my gif?

Comment: Ah, yes. It is selecting the image by it's id.

Comment: So I am guessing I would need to put the image somewhere on the page and give it an id, but just hid it right?

Comment: That's right. By setting the css to `display: none` the image will be hidden by default.

Comment: Thats should be all I need to get started.  Thanks.